# Rails 4 - Validate Elements in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

One of my models contains a virtual attribute called `things`. This attribute is an array, and I'd like every element within that array to be validated against a set of rules. Here is my current attempt at validation:

```
validates :things, presence: true,  length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 255 }
```

The problem with this code is that it validates the entire array itself, not each individual element within the array. I know I can write a custom validator, but is there any way to use the existing validation options to run these validations against every element in the array? The other topics I found on this are for older versions of Rails, so I'm not sure if Rails 4 has something new that could help with this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a custom validation? You can create a custom validation inside your model.

Something like this, where "things" is the name of the attribute that you want to validate:

### model.rb

```
validate :check_each_thing

def check_each_thing
  things.each do |thing|
    if thing.present?
      if thing.size < 2 || thing.size > 255
        errors.add(:things, 'It should be longer than 2 and shorter than 255.')
      end
    else
      errors.add(:things, 'It should be present.')
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Demi, thank you for the answer! As I mentioned in my question, I know I can write a custom validator, but I wanted to see if there is another way to accomplish this. It seems like this is my only option. Thank you for the help!